# DNN language control does not work

Tags: .net, internationalization, dotnetnuke

I have a few ASP.NET pages under DNN 8. I have installed slovenian language, and a pair of country-flag images appeared on a toolbar, just like it should. 
Problem is that my CurrentCulture is always en-us. Current URL is [servername]/[pagename], without culture infix. American flag contains hyper link to same URL ([servername]/[pagename]), and Slovenian flag is without hyper link. I have tried to add URL infix by hand ([servername]/en-us/[pagename], or [servername]/sl-si/[pagename]), but those locations do not exist.
I have checked language settings - *Enable Language Parameter in URLs?*  checkbox is ticked. 
How can I really enable that language infix in URL ? What else should I configure ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution about enabling of URL variations with language infix :
Go to *Admin/Site-Settings*, choose *advances settings*, then *site aliases*; add aliases with infixes for language (for example sl-si) for URL. 
Those aliases should be language-aware. You can write those URLs into browser by hand, and test if they work.

Now we should add web-control which allows user to toggle between those URL variations. DNN provides that control :

```
<dnn:LANGUAGE runat="server" ID="dnnLANGUAGE" ShowMenu="False" ShowLinks="True" />
```

You can add it to any of your web pages. Bellow top of page add another line :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LANGUAGE" Src="~/Admin/Skins/Language.ascx" %>
```

Now I am still looking for a way to add this control to some of DNN's controls (for example - menu toolbar), so it can be visible from all of my modules.
Any ideas ?